# The Great American Beer Festival Meetup of 2012

Tags: discussion

Often stack exchange sites have events to help bring the community together. We have not had any on site events in the past so I am bringing forward a suggestion from chat.

**What:** The Great American Beer Festival Meetup of 2012

**When:** October 11-13(Thursday-Saturday), 2012

**Where:** Colorado Convention Center, Hall D, E, & F, Downtown Denver, Colorado, USA.

**Who:** All EE.SE Users, their friends, family and acquaintances also.

A [meetup.com group has been made](http://www.meetup.com/The-EE-Great-American-Beer-Festival-Meetup-Group/) but is currently a work in progress. The meetup group allows people to propose times to do just as the name says, Meet up.

Suggested events here would be a great idea, the meetup site is designed to allow you to suggest events there.. I will be editing this with further information about the event as I collect it.

Comment: This is a meta post because we still lack a blog. Please share ideas as you want with answers. If there is something you think would match up well with the event please post it as an answer.

Comment: What about a meetup at Microchip Masters this summer?  Anyone interested?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, and I was so sure I would entice you with a couple days of good beer! Post a topic asking for interest and see who will be willing.  I would really like to but I have already scheduled both my vacation plans and used my current vacation buildup. I know I can next year.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I do hope you are able to attend both :)

Comment: I'll be at Masters, but traveling 2000 miles one way for a beer fest sounds a bit extravagant.  I doubt I'd go to a beer fest if it was next door.

Comment: @OlinLathrop :( I could hope. Sounded like a fun event. Hopefully it will play out well. At the end of the year I will ask for events people would like to take part in and see if there is something like ESC people are interested in. Try to schedule a few events next year. I would love an excuse to travel to Europe or Asia.

Comment: Maybe the embedded systems conference in Boston? It's usually some time in September. I generally stop by one day to wander thru the exhibition.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I thought they had reduced the number of conferences but I have yet to have a chance to attend so I am not expert on that. If I picked a conference it would be ESC. Boston would be a great city to visit.

Comment: Just to point out that the drinking age in the states is 21, im 19 :'(.

Answer (score 2):

Denver has a reasonable public-transport system, especially to/from the downtown area.   Go to http://www.rtd-denver.com/ to see about buses and the light rail.  Also, Google Maps will allow you to choose different modes of transport, and bus is one of them.  It'll generate your route based on the bus schedule.

The airport is far from Downtown, 45-60 minutes.  While hotels in Downtown will be more expensive, if you find one with a free airport shuttle and you don't have to rent a car then you might break even.

I highly recommend that you plan your transportation to/from GABF in advance.  You will be blitzed and the cops will be carefully watching for drunk drivers.  The GABF offers discounts and stuff for designated drivers.  I live in the suburbs and always take the public bus for this event and it works out well.

Answer (score 2):

As a promotion for this site I am changing my gravitar to have a mug of beer in it. This is to give something users will notice on the site. My new gravitar will be:

[image: New gravitar with beer]

From two of my favorite beers:

[image: Yeti beer with great divide brewery label on mug]
[image: Trois Pistoles with Unibroue brewer label mug]

I am inviting others to join in this promotion method.

Comment: I should downvote you for not posing with a Belgian beer!! ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh, I am a lover of Belgian beer but they are so expensive that I dont get them as often here. There are many Belgian style breweries here, for example, the beer on the left is brewed by a brewery that does almost all Belgian style! I almost picked a Kwak as one of my beers for fun.

Comment: The beer which gets chosen as the best every year is "Westvleteren" [west-vlay-t-ren]. Hard to get: it's not for sale in shops, and except for cafés you can only get it at the abbey where they brew it in a very small time window, a couple of weeks a year.

Comment: @stevenvh, Ohh yes, are you going to put a picture of it into your gravatar? I hope to one day be able to enjoy it. I consider kwak a fun light beer, not a serious competitor, although I do greatly enjoy its flavor. I am more of a heavy Quad or imperial stout man myself. We have had many a discussion of beer/whiskey in chat, it was the source of the idea for this event.

Comment: @stevenvh: Does Achel count as belgian? ;)

Comment: @clabacchio - Sure, [it does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achel_Brewery)! Are you asking because you know it's on the Dutch border (I know you're in nearby Eindhoven)? Have you already learned some Dutch in the mean time?

Comment: @stevenvh: hehe I know it's close to the border, I went there by bike (and I'm going to do it again :). Sadly my Dutch is evolving very slowly, I'm using English all the time. But I've been teasing Kortuk for the fact that I have an abbey so close to home

Comment: As soon as I get my hands on some bottles of Westvleteren 12 (chosen to be the best beer in the world), I'll change my  avatar too. It is extremely difficult to get your hands on though :-(

Comment: @clabacchio La Trappe is Dutch too, and brewed not too far from Eindhoven. Actualy de Koningshoeve is near Tilburg and you should definately try the quadruple 'Oak Aged'.

Comment: @jippie: yes, I've read about that :) Achel is closer, but I tried both the Tripel and the Dubbel from La Trappe

Comment: I should then add a picture of some RFNA? - among  the most potent brews you can get.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I go for flavor of beer, can I get a link to RFNA?

Answer (score 0):

### How are the sessions broken up?

There will be 3 sessions for the general public to purchase tickets to and 1 session if you are a member of the Amateur Homebrewers Association.

[image: Beer festival Session Times]

Tickets are priced at [65 dollars a session](http://www.greatamericanbeerfestival.com/tickets/ticket-faq/). They can be [purchased starting August 2nd at 10 am MST](http://www.greatamericanbeerfestival.com/tickets/purchase-tickets/).

Comment: Wow. Olin said 2k miles are too much for him - for me, it would be > 2k miles and a transcon flight. Besides, we Bavarians tend to not spend .065 k$ to just get in - we have beer gardens. Seriously, I guess meeting some of you guys would be fun, but please excuse me for not making it to this event.

Comment: @zebonaut Wish you could make it. I understand the distance issues. It is .065k$ for unlimited drinks during the event, I think 2200 craft beers.